# Regex does not match all characters

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

s = "aaacccbbbbccbbbbbb"
print(re.search(r"(?:.*)(c+b{3,})", s).group(1))
```

The result is "cbbbbbb". Why not "ccbbbbbb"

I need everyone's "c" before "bbbbbb"

Comment: `.*?(c+b{3,})`.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `.*` backtracks until the first occurrence of `c` where it can fulfill matching 3  consecutive `b` chars, which in this case is `cbbbbbb`

You can add a negative lookbehind to assert not `c` before matching the first occurrence of `c` which will capture `ccbbbbbb`

Note that you don't need the non capture group `(?:.*)`

```
.*(?<!c)(c+b{3,})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdGrg9/1)

If there must be a single non whitespace character before it, you could also use a negated character class `[^\sc]`

```
.*[^\sc](c+b{3,})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9BMuEK/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by [@TheFourthBird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78093553/9758194) gives enough insight as to the *why*, so I'll focus on *how* to tackle this in just one more way to add to the given alternatives:

```
c+b{3,}(?!.*cbbb)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3fjvq/1). The idea you are implementing using `.*` is that you want to capture the very last occurence of `c+b{3,}`, so to make that happen in just one more different way is to use a negative lookahead to assert there is no more occurence of the pattern after the most recent captured one. In other words:

- `c+b{3,}` - The exact pattern you wish to find, one or more (greedy) c's followed by at least 3 b's;
- `(?!.*cbbb)` - Negative lookahead to assert that there are no 0+ (greedy) characters and exactly the substring 'cbbb'.

---

One more fun little alternative *reversing* your search from right to left using [PyPi's regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module:

```
import regex as re
s = 'aaacccbbbbccbbbbbb'
print(re.search(r'(?r)c+b{3,}',s).group(0))
```

Or, use `re.findall()` which will return a list of all occurences of your pattern and simple slice the last one:

```
import re
s = 'aaacccbbbbccbbbbbb'
print(re.findall(r'(c+b{3,})',s)[-1])
```

Both options return: `ccbbbbbb`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more accurate regular expression to match the pattern that "c" comes before a string of at least three **"b"s.**
The goal is to include all **"c"s** that come before a string of three or more "b"s in the match.

```
import re
s = "aaacccbbbbccbbbbbb"
# Adjusted pattern to ensure all 'c's before 'bbbbbb' are included
pattern = r"(c+?b{6})"

match = re.search(pattern, s)
if match:
    print("The result is:", match.group(1))
else:
    print("No match found.")
```

1. To keep characters that could be part of the "ccbbbbb" sequence from
   being used, start the pattern with a non-greedy quantifier.
2. I think from this approach you can get all 'c's first then b will follow along.

The regex pattern r"(c+?b{6})" will search for "c"s (c+? is non-greedy), followed by exactly six "b"s (b{6}).

I think the above will helpful for you to solve the regex problem.
For get more insights in regex, this site will be helpful for you :-
https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-greedy version of `*`:

```
# *?, not * --------------V
>>> print(re.search(r"(?:.*?)(c+b{3,})", s).group(1))
cccbbbb
```

Here, `(?:.*?)` matches as *few* characters as possible before matching `(c+b{3,})`, rather than matching as *many* as possible while still allowing `(c+b{3,})` to match.

Note that this captures the *first* matching group now. If you use `re.findall`, you'll see there are two non-overlapping groups that match `(c+b{3,})`:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r"(?:.*?)(c+b{3,})", s))
['cccbbbb', 'ccbbbbbb']
```

If you want the second one, you should probably tweak the capture group to reflect what makes `ccbbbbbb` the desirable result.